# Does a symbol or set of symbols exist to identify the least positive non zero remainder classes of a modulus?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, terminology

$\mathbb{Z}^+$ is the set of all positive integers $\{1,2,3,...\}$. $\mathbb{Z}_n$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ represents the residue classes modulo $n$.  Using symbols is there a way to represent the least positive non zero remainder classes modulo $11$. For example, the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$?  I'm trying to find a way to refer to the set other than "the least positive non zero integer remainder class" which is kind of a mouthful, however, if that's the most accurate I'll use it.

Comment: Nonzero remainders modulo 11.

Comment: @Wuestenfux not being argumentative, but does this imply the smallest set modulo 11? That is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, versus {12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21}? Looking back at my question I think I've confused "class" with "set".

Comment: For prime numbers, it's $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$, but for non-prime numbers, this notation is actually used for a set of classes whose representative is co-prime to $n$. But, as far as I know, and understood the question, there is no such notation for "*the least positive non zero integer remainder class*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard symbol. That said, the residue classes modulo $n$ are often implicitly and informally identified with the integers $0, 1, \ldots, n-1$ so you could probably use $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for that set and $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ for its nonzero elements if you were not doing formal abstract algebra proofs and explained your usage at the start of your document.

In most programming languages   `a % n` returns an integer in that set, so if your context is computer science your readers may even think you overly pedantic.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at Gregory (not me) and Krishnamurthy's book on error free computation.The most commonly used alternative e.g. would be {-2,-1,0,1,2,3} for $\mathbb Z_6$ and {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3} for $\mathbb Z_7$

Comment: Did you mean $0, 1, ..., n\color{red}{-1}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes thanks fixed. You could have.

Comment: In most programming languages the `%` operator produces different representatives when the left operand is negative. (This is motivated by being consistent with an integer division operator that rounds towards zero, though in my own experience it is something you need to work around more often than it is the behavior you need ...)